# transition effect not working on hover with linear-gradient to bottom

Tags: css, css-transitions, linear-gradients

I have two boxes, each have :hover selector which transition linear-gradient background image.
linear gradient to top works perfectly fine with transition (code below).

```
.box7:hover{
            color: #FFF; 
            background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #000 50%, #fff 50%);
            background-position: 0% 100%;
            background-size: 100% 200%;
            transition: all 1s ease;
            border: none;
        }
```

but I am having problems with linear gradient to bottom, transition effect doesn't seems to work (code below).

```
.box2:hover{
            color: #FFF; 
            background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #000 50%, #fff 50%);
            background-position: 100% 0%;
            background-size: 100% 200%;
            transition: all 1s ease;
            border: none;
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Below is the link to check (hover on all boxes)
https://conrad93.github.io/linear-gradient-sliding-effect/boxbox.html

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your styles are not applied when you aren't hovering over the element. The solution is therefore to apply these styles to the default state of the element as well. Something like this:

```
// html

<div class="container">
  <div class="box box-1"></div>
  <div class="box box-2"></div>
  <div class="box box-3"></div>
  <div class="box box-4"></div>
</div>

//  CSS

.container {
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: solid 1px red;
  margin: 5px;
  transition: all .4s ease;
  background-color: lightgoldenrodyellow;
}

.box-1 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, crimson 50%, lightgoldenrodyellow 50%);
  background-position: 0% 0%;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.box-1:hover {
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}

.box-2 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, crimson 50%, lightgoldenrodyellow 50%);
  background-position: 0% -100%;
  background-size: 100% 200%;
}

.box-2:hover {
  background-position: 0% -200%;
}

.box-3 {
  background-color: crimson;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom left, crimson 50%, lightgoldenrodyellow 50%);
  background-position: 0% 100%;
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box-3:hover {
  background-position: 0% -100%;
}

.box-4 {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top right, crimson 50%, lightgoldenrodyellow 50%);
  background-position: 0% -100%;
  background-size: 200% 200%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.box-4:hover {
  background-position: 0% 100%;
}
```

Within the declaration block for the hover state, you only need to declare those properties that are changing, in this case `background-position`.

Here is a working example on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Richardinho/qv4z2pua/).

You probably also want the diagonal gradient to animate up from the bottom left of the element. This is a little tricky to do, but you can see it working in the example. To understand why it works, you need to understand what the x and y values in the `background-position` property mean. [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-position) are a good place to learn.

Comment: can u show me in linear gradient to bottom, in my code to top works but not in to bottom

Comment: Yes, I added that to the example. Other directions, e.g. left to right, just follow the same pattern.